# Entity Framework está inserindo duplicado a cada SaveChanges

Tags: c#

Olá, estou utilizando uma técnica para conseguir inserir muitas entidades no banco de dados, estou utilizando C#, EntityFramework e SQL server.

Exemplo

```
List<Editora> editoras = new List<Editora>();
Editora editora1 = new Editora() { ID = 1, nome = "Teste" };

foreach(Livro livro in livros) {
    editora.livros.Add(livro);
}
```

Agora vou inserir no banco de dados da seguinte forma

```
context.livros.AddRange(livros);
```

Essa abordagem funciona perfeitamente, porem supondo existir 1.000.000 de livros, demora muito e na maioria das vezes ultrapassa meu limite de memória RAM.

Então eu utilizei a técnica *batch-insert* encontrada [nesta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/5741268)

Dessa forma eu insiro de 100 em 100 por exemplo e chamo a função `SaveChanges`.

O problema é que ao inserir as notas da editora 1, e posteriormente inserir as notas da editora 2, é inserido tudo de novo as notas da editora 1.

Acho isso muito estranho pois eu recriei o contexto e adicionei somente as notas da editora 2 ao contexto novo. Como o Etity Framework esta adicionando tudo de novo algo do contexto antigo?

Comment: Precisa ver o que está fazendo, a parte que realmente importa não foi colocada.

Comment: Se está igual ao exemplo experimente usar o    context = new MyDbContext();

em um bloco using